Applicability of Kinetic Theory on mixture of 2 gases with different molecular masses
In kinetic theory of gases, we neglect the gravity and do the calculations.
Today, I was reading about convection when I saw that gravity is must for convection to occur. This got me thinking about kinetic theory. If a microscopic process like convection is so dependent on gravity, then how can we actually neglect gravity in KTG?
So, I feel that when we mix 2 gases of different molecular masses,that is different densities, we should consider gravity, which implies that the higher molecular mass gas is at the bottom and the lower at the top, just like what happens in convection.
So, why are we actually neglecting gravity in KTG even if it plays a big role( I think)? Has it got something to do with the difference in the way the density difference is created?
Temperature difference for convection and molar mass difference in case of the KTG part.


You don't need to exclude the gravity, the apparatus of statistical mechanics works just as well with external potentials (that way you can, e.g., also study cold atom gases in a trap potential). The result is that an external potential does not change the velocity distribution, but just the probability of a particle being in a place. So with gravity you get the usual equation of state with height dependent pressure according to the barometric formula. This is a bit unwieldy (e.g. as you can't change to an ensemble with constant pressure), so normally it is not done that way (see the next point). The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution gets a correction like $p(\vec v, \vec r) \propto e^{- \big(\frac 1 2mv^2 + V(\vec r) \big) /kT}$.

Usually, when looking at non-equilibrium phenomena (like convection or flowing media) you make the assumption of local-equilibrium. That a parcel of fluid moving with the flow is assumed to be in equilibrium at all times. This is an approximation, but it works very well (because the thermal relaxation times are very small). This way, the thermodynamic analysis for a static fluid without external forces is sufficient as an input to the approximate theory.

In equilibrium gases with components with different masses will not layer like immiscible liquids. Rather, in the ideal gas limit, each species will independently follow the barometric formula (which changes the relative mixture with height). When considering interactions between the molecules there will be corrections, but they are small. For each of the species the particle density will be highest at the bottom. You can layer gases of different molecular weight temporarily (e.g. you can pour $\mathrm{SF_6}$ in a beaker and it will stay there for a while), but in time diffusion will mix them.



I don't know much about the math of maxwell distribution. What I get is that there is essentially not much change if we include gravity also. Is it also true for larger accelerations?
